# using cyphejor with projectile

Tags: projectile, cyphejor

[Make names of major modes shorter in the mode-line](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/16545/make-names-of-major-modes-shorter-in-the-mode-line) describes a way to shorten the modeline with cypejor. However, it seems like projectile-mode is not shortened by cyphejor. Is there anything that needs to be added to the config? Example:

```
(setq
 cyphejor-rules
 '(:upcase
   ("projectile" "P")
   ("menu"        "▤" :postfix)
   ("mode"        "")
   ("package"     "↓")
   ("python"      "π")
   ("shell"       "sh" :postfix)
))
(cyphejor-mode 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the question still remains, [projectile can itself shorten its mode line part](https://projectile.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration/#mode-line-indicator):

> - `projectile-mode-line-prefix` (by default " Projectile") controls the static part of the mode-line
> - `projectile-dynamic-mode-line` (by default t) controls whether to display the project name & type part of the mode-line